# Different sympy expression results

Tags: python, sympy

First I want to point out that I'm a total `sympy` noob.

I'm trying to create a [Custom Formula-based Measurement](http://python-measurement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/creating_your_own_class.html#using-formula-based-conversions) class with this `sympy` expression:

```
from sympy import Symbol, S, floor, sympify, Float
SU = Symbol('millimeter')
exp = S(20.0) + floor((((SU-S(212.5)) / S(10.0))) / S(0.5)) * S(0.5)
```

The problem I face is that for the same `SU` I get different result based on the way the expression is evaluated. Here is what I mean:

```
>>> exp.subs(SU, 215)
20.0000000000000
>>> exp.evalf(subs={SU: 215})
0.e+1 #This is actually 16.0 when: float(exp.evalf(subs={SU: 215}))
```

More interestingly the problem exists only when `SU` is between [213:217] (when I expect the result to be `20.0`)
For the rest of the values its fine (AFAIK)

```
>>> exp.subs(SU, 212)
19.5000000000000
>>> exp.evalf(subs={SU: 212})
19.50
>>> exp.subs(SU, 218)
20.5000000000000
>>> exp.evalf(subs={SU: 218})
20.50
```

Any Ideas for this strange behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to incorrect precision values. The bug was [reported](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13359) and is already corrected in the current version of SymPy available on [GitHub](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/); the versions of SymPy > 1.1.1 will not have this bug.

---

Using `srepr` on the output of `subs` provides some explanation:

```
x = Symbol('x')
srepr((floor(x)+20).evalf(subs={x:0.5}))
```

The output is `Float('16.0', precision=1)`. This is *binary* precision. SymPy thinks that the output of `floor`, when it happens to be zero, has only one bit of precision. So it subsequently truncates the added +20 accordingly, to nearest power of 2.

Of course, this is a bug. There are several open issues related to Float class and rounding, such as [this one](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12056); they may be related.

The workaround is to avoid `evalf(subs=dict)` construction (is it even documented?). Using the methods in the natural order: substitute, then evaluate, gives correct results:

```
srepr((floor(x)+20).subs({x:0.5}).evalf())
"Float('20.0', precision=53)"
```

Comment: 10x, I've no Idea how documented is this approach, its just how `python-measurement`  [do it](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/python-measurement/blob/1.8.0/measurement/base.py#L338). I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/python-measurement/issues/19) there.